# Submitting a form from a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to submit a form from a modal generated in a partial view. And I don't know how to get back the submitted form.

Here is the view:

```
@model Myproject.ViewModels.GetMonitorFromDeviceViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetMonitorFromDevice";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/ManagementPage.cshtml";
}

<div id="Accordion">
    @{
        foreach (var type in Model.AvailableTypesAvailableMonitors)
        {
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@type">
                        @type
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="@type" class="collapse show">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @{
                            foreach (var monitor in Model.ActiveMonitors)
                            {
                                if (monitor.Type == @type)
                                {
                                    <p>
                                        @monitor.Name
                                        <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btnEdit" onclick="createModal('@Url.Action("NameMonitor", "DeviceManager" , new { idDevice = monitor.DeviceOwner.ID, monitorName = monitor.Name })')">Details</span>
                                    </p>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

And here is my modal at the bottom of the page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modelContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function createModal(url) {
        $('#modelContent').load(url);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

And finally, here is my partial view that is displayed as a modal:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.NameMonitorModal
@using (Html.BeginForm("NameMonitor", "DeviceManager", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.TrueName } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TrueName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdDevice)

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save name" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In my controller, I have an action for my partial view called ActionResult NameMonitor.
In order to catch the submited form, I tried to add another action with the [HttpPost] tag with the same name but doesn't work.  I also tried to use the main page action with the [HttpPost] tag but it doesn't work either.  As you can see, I have specified the action and controller in the form itself but its still not working.
Now, I'm a little bit out of idea of how I can get the information from my modal back.

Comment: Is the `NameMonitor` action in your `DeviceManager` controller? Does it accept a `GetMonitorFromDeviceViewModel` as its parameter?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work" does it hit the action at all? Is the parameter null in the action?

Comment: @Valuator: The `NameMonitor` action is in my `DeviceManager` controller and it accepts the view model of my partial view: `NameMonitorModal`.  

@Chris: It never hit the action in my controller.  My modal is simply closing itself and I don't see any other action done.

Comment: in your browser use the dev tools and look at the console, there's probably a 404 error then, as in it can't find the route generated. If that's the case then it isn't an issue involving the markup so much as it is an issue with the routing and it should tell you the url it cannot find so see what that is. I have a feeling you're expecting the route to be something like "localhost:xxx/DeviceManager/NameMonitor" and it's formulating that correctly.

Comment: Please post the code for the MVC Post Controller method NameMonitor. Usually POST controller methods return JSON or XML, not a view or a redirection. Also parameter matching in post requests on mvc net might be a little tricky. I don't see input type elements inside your BeginForm (only input elements will be submited).

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci `EditorFor` and `HiddenFor` will generate input elements for the Model properties in the form.

Comment: @chris-crush-code In the dev tools, I can see the `Get` request to display my modal but when I close it with the submit button, it doesn't send anything.  I don't understand why.  As if it was not submitting my form. 
I checked other forms in my application and each time I clearly see the `Post` request sent by the form.  But nothing in this case.

Comment: As the other commenter pointed out the data-dismiss attribute may be hijacking the click event. Try as a test removing that so the button is just a plain submit button and see if that hits your controller. Also, if all the form fields are on the modal, I'd probably move the form into the modal. Anyways, try that and see what happpens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-dismiss="modal"` will close the modal without submitting the form, see [Dismiss and submit form Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679867/dismiss-and-submit-form-bootstrap-3)

You can change the submit button to call a JavaScript function to submit the form, then close the modal.

```
function submitModal() {
    $('#myFormId').submit();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what was happening! Now everything works as expected.